# Bind click function of child href to parent div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
<div class="parent">
   <a href="#">download link</a>
</div>


$(".parent").bind("click", function(){

alert('test');

});
```

would like to bind the href click function so that when the .parent is clicked it goes to the location of the nested link.

Comment: give full requirement. actually what do you want to do.?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".parent").bind("click", function(){
    alert($(this).children('a').attr('href'));
});​
```

Answer (score 8):

```
$(".parent").bind("click", function(){
    window.location.href = $(".parent a").attr("href");
});
```

Comment: window.location.href = $(this).find('a').attr('href'); //this works better with different <a> links

Answer (score 2):

Since you have only one link inside a parent element, you can totally avoid javascript if your link fills entirely the parent width and height: just set this CSS

```
.parent a {
   display: block;
   width  : 100%;  /* or set in px if parent has not width specified */
   height : 100%;  /* or set in px if parent has not height specified */
}
```

Comment: I would avoid doing this in js except in this case i have a carousel which has many links. thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following, it should work:

```
$(".parent a").bind("click", function(){
    alert('test');    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Then you can do something like that :

```
// Choose the a tag specifically
$(".parent").bind("click", function() {
    alert($(this).find('a').attr('href'));
});
```

That should do the trick

Good luck!

Comment: amritpal has a better version as `children()` only browses the first level of children. `find()` browses all the levels and is therefore more greedy